# What is the pattern used to name the fields accessible through the API?

Tags: api

I'm getting familiar with the API and having trouble understanding the pattern used to name fields.

A call like **`CRM.api3('Address', 'get')`** makes sense to me because the fields in the result are (1) named consistently, and (2) each named exactly as they appear in MySQL. I see things like `street_address`, `location_type_id`, and `is_primary`. I like this.

A call like **`CRM.api3('Activity', 'get')`** produces fields which make slightly less sense. I see `subject` and `status_id` which seem consistent. Good. But then I see `activity_date_time` and `activity_type_id` and become confused about why some fields are named with their entity as a prefix and some are not... *But* at the very least, all these field names are consistent with the column names in MySQL. Ok fine, I can live with that.

But then when I look at the same call for **`Contribution`**, I get even more confused. I see fields like `contribution_check_number` which seem to have an *added* prefix, not present from MySQL. Why?

And when I look at **`Participant`**, *all* the fields have a `participant_` prefix. Huh??

Is there some sort of underlying pattern that can explain this madness to my logic-seeking brain?

Comment: I suspect the answer is, "Many cooks in the kitchen."

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons (namely cramming a bunch of fields from various entities into a flat array for e.g. a profile form) some fields in the database have a "unique_name" which is generally the entity prefixing the field name. For obscure reasons, the api v3 sometimes returns those "unique_names" instead of the regular field names.

I personally hate the implementation of unique names in CiviCRM - it's inconsistent and confusing and if I have anything to say about it there will be *no* unique names in api v4!